# Cordova in app browser works on browser but not on android phone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I m trying to open an external link for connecting to dropbox. When i try it on the browser, everything is fine.A Pop up opens for authentication as expected. But when i try it on the phone after converting to apk, it doesnt work.
Any ideas what am i doing wrong ?

```
 connectDroppbox() {
      let dbx = new Dropbox({ clientId: this.CLIENT_ID });
      let str = dbx.getAuthenticationUrl("http://localhost:8100");
      var browserRef  = this.$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(str, '_blank', this.defaultOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let str = dbx.getAuthenticationUrl("http://localhost:8100");
```

This url won't work while in an app. What would be localhost in that case? Itself?

Comment: localhost doesnt work as well.. Actually if i only could be able to close the inAppBrowser after i got redirected and got the token, that would be awesome :/ But after redirecting, no  inAppBrowser events are fired. so cant detect that browser redirected to another url. :(

Comment: You would have to use the external IP address of you server